Beamer - image.png not displayed
I have an issue about an image not displayed despite usepackage and all my tests.
\documentclass[aspectratio=43, draft]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{mygray}{gray}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white}, 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       
  breakatwhitespace=false,        
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{orange},   
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},        
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                  
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
  language=Prolog,                
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray},
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,          
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=2,                    
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},   
  tabsize=2,                      
  title=\lstname,                  
  morekeywords={not,\},\{,preconditions,effects },            
  deletekeywords={time}            
}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page
\title[Test] %optional
{Test}


\author[Zazie] % (optional)
{Zazie}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}


%---------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code is for the table of contents after
%the title page
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------


\section{Présentation}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%Changing visivility of the text
\begin{frame}{Présentation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    Nombre de joueur : 2\newline
    Plateau de taille : $14\times14$ \newline
    Nombre de pièces : 21\newline
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3, center]{image.png}
     \caption{\scriptsize Issu du document de Chin Hung Chao, Blokus Game Solver}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Thanks in advance

You are disabling images with draft

Remove \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} In the best case it isn't necessary, in the worst case it brings you into trouble.

I did what you advised, and removing the \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} got me into trouble.

There is an easy solution: only load packages which you need for a certain document. Then you won't run into problems like this.


you are disabling images with the draft option
Remove \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}. In the best case it isn't necessary, in the worst case (like in your example) it brings you into trouble.

Minimal working example:
\documentclass[
  aspectratio=43,
%  draft
]{beamer}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

In your not so minimal code:
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{mygray}{gray}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green}

\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme{default}

\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white}, 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       
  breakatwhitespace=false,        
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{orange},   
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},        
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                  
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
  language=Prolog,                
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray},
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,          
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=2,                    
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},   
  tabsize=2,                      
  title=\lstname,                  
  morekeywords={not,\},\{,preconditions,effects },            
  deletekeywords={time}            
}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page
\title[Test] %optional
{Test}


\author[Zazie] % (optional)
{Zazie}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}


%---------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code is for the table of contents after
%the title page
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------


\section{Présentation}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%Changing visivility of the text
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Présentation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    Nombre de joueur : 2\newline
    Plateau de taille : $14\times14$ \newline
    Nombre de pièces : 21\newline
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-duck}
     \caption{\scriptsize Issu du document de Chin Hung Chao, Blokus Game Solver}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


My code isn't compiled

@ZazieLin The code in my answer compiles without problems. If you have a new problem, make a minimal reproducible example and ask a new question and show the error message.

Thanks I thrust it is may be about on of my insertion
